# why doesn't this post?

Tags: php, post

It gives me this error when I try to load the page: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\vitamin-k-tracker\testing-form-checkboxes.php on line 3

I figure there's some error in $_POST[  $row["id"]  ] because it's so basic.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST[  $row["id"]  ]) && !empty($_POST[ $row["id"] ])){
    print_r($_POST);
}

?>



<form action="testing-form-checkboxes.php" method="POST">     
<?php $row["id"]= 'a'; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value="aa" />

<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Food to my Meal Planner Queue">

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `$_POST[ $row["id"] ]` before you define it. Move `<?php $row["id"]= 'a'; ?>` to line 1.

Answer (score 2):

Uh... the variable doesn't exist. Did you perhaps mean to query a database first?

Answer (score 1):

`$row["id"]` is never defined, so you can't check if `$_POST[  $row["id"]  ]` is defined.

You might want to try getting the row first :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make much sense to me:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST[  $row["id"]  ]) && !empty($_POST[ $row["id"] ])){
    print_r($_POST);
}

?>
```

Are you sure you're not looking for $_POST['id']? The error is because $row is not defined as stated in this code. It may be in your actual code but since you didn't post that we don't know.

I can see what your code IS doing. I can see you call your input name="a" but again, this method doesn't make sense to me. I have never encountered a situation where I would need to make a form this "loose"